# Creation of spatial index locks the table for hours

Tags: index, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I used this code to create a spatial index in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SPATIAL_COMPANIES_GEO ON dbo.ITEMS(GEO) USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID
 WITH( 
          GRIDS  = ( LEVEL_1  = HIGH, LEVEL_2  = HIGH, LEVEL_3  = HIGH, LEVEL_4  = HIGH)
        , CELLS_PER_OBJECT  = 100
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
     )
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.COMPANIES SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
```

This query executes in 5 seconds, but then the table `ITEMS` seems to be locked for hours. In Management Studio I cannot expand the Indexes folder for `ITEMS` and any query to that table times out. Furthermore, if I restart the  SQL Server service the spatial index I just created disappears.

I've tried this on my production database with 3.000.000 records and also on my test database with 300.000 records with the same result.

Is this normal? What I should do to create the index without locking the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start a transaction but don't commit the 2nd one, so the table will remain locked.
The SQL Server restart will rollback the transaction containing the CREATE INDEX

Remove **both** `BEGIN TRANSACTION` calls and the`COMMIT`
(or add a final `COMMIT TRAN`)

Comment: There is a `COMMIT` before the second `BEGIN TRAN`.  I don't think setting changes can be rolled back anyways, but he has it encapsulated!

Comment: @JNK: I was scanning for COMMIT TRANSACTION to match BEGIN TRANSACTION. This is definitely SSMS generated code

Comment: Yes it is a SSMS generated code. anyway i removed the ALTER TABLE statement as really i can't understand why SSMS added it... THANK YOU GUYS!